# Setting multi-finger swipe action on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

My laptop has a precision touchpad- I can do the three or four fingers swipe on it. But in `mouse settings` in Windows, I can't edit `action` part of each type of swipe; it doesn't have the option. So it's set on `default`.

How can I set or change the actions of these swipes?

Comment: You have installed the Windows 10 drivers for your touchpad, correct?

Comment: yeah i installed windows 10 64bit driver for dell touchpad.

Comment: Feel free to update your question so I can delete my comment.

Comment: the problem isn't solved yet :| why should you delete your comment ?!

Comment: Because once you update your question it serves zero purpose.  So feel free to update your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this small program called [MultiSwipe](https://www.multiswipe.com/). First, run the test program to see whether the touchpad is supported.